# cassandra, secondary indexes building during adding of a new node lasts forever

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I'm trying to add new node to our cluster (cassandra 2.1.11, 16 nodes, 32Gb ram, 2x3Tb hdd, 8core cpu, 1 datacenter, 2 racks, about 700Gb of data on each node). After start of new node, data (approx 600Gb total) from 16 existing nodes successfully transfered to new node and building of secondary indexes starts. The process of secondary indexes building looks normal, i see info about successfull completition of some secondary indexes building and some stream tasks:

```
INFO  [StreamReceiveTask:9] 2015-11-22 02:15:23,153 StreamResultFuture.java:180 - [Stream #856adc90-8ddd-11e5-a4be-69bddd44a709] Session with /192.168.21.66 is complete

INFO  [StreamReceiveTask:9] 2015-11-22 02:15:23,152 SecondaryIndexManager.java:174 - Index build of [docs.docs_ex_pl_ph_idx, docs.docs_lo_pl_ph_idx, docs.docs_author_login_idx, docs.docs_author_extid_idx, docs.docs_url_idx] complete
```

Curently 9 out of 16 streams successfully finished, according to logs. Everything looks fine, except one issue: this process already lasts 5 full days. There is no errors in logs, no anything suspicious, except extremely slow progress.

```
nodetool compactionstats -H
```

shows

```
   Secondary index build   ...    docs    882,4 MB   1,69 GB   bytes     51,14%
```

So there is some process of index building and it has some progress, but very slow, 1% in half a hour or so.

The only significant difference between the new node and any of existing nodes is the fact that cassandra java process has 21k open files, in contrast of 300 open files on any existing node, and 80k files in the data dir on new node in contrast of 300-500 files in the data dir on any existing node.

Is it normal? At this speed it looks i'll spend 16 weeks or so to add 16 more nodes.

Comment: Did you set streaming socket timeout?

Comment: no i didn't, _streaming_socket_timeout_in_ms_ property is commented out in config, and i think there is no socket related issues since all data already transfered to the destination node, now it builds secondary indexes and does it very slow

Comment: Secondary index builds are very slow but if you're hanging indefinitely it may be due to a streaming session so make sure you set socket timeout going forward.

Comment: Can you afford to drop the indexes? They don't perform well in production queries anyway.

Comment: Actually i can't drop it and btw it works adequately for my queries. The index building process is not seems stalled, it actually has some progress, it just very slow despite the fact that there is a lot of free unused cpu/disk/mem resources on the target node.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but we ran into this exact issue with 2.1.13 using DTCS.  We were able to fix it in our test environment by increasing memtable flush thresholds to `0.7` - which didn't make any sense to us, but may be worth trying.

Comment: thanks for an answer, in my case the solution mainly was in increasing of  number of simultaneous compactions from one (default) to seven